# Adding dynamic content to the page before showing it in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

In my jQuery mobile, Phonegap  app I have a page in which there is a list view , this list content is added dynamically , the problem is that when i navigate to this page its firstly shown empty and after seconds the List view added to the page and shown  , I have used pagebeforeshow  event to add the list view content before showing the page but it didn't work for me " the list view is shown after showing the page " and the user will notice  and see the content while its added to the page. How can i solve this problem so the list content added before showing the page ? please help me ..

Thanks in advance .

Html

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="EmployeesListPage">

<div  data-role="header"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false" data- fullscreen="false"   data-theme="b">
<h3> Employees</h3>
</div>

<div data-role="content">

<ul data-role="listview"   id="EmpList"   data-inset="true"  data-filter="true" data-  filter-placeholder="Search " data-split-icon="delete"  style="margin-top: 30px;" > 

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Java Script

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
    loading('show');

    $('#EmployeesListPage').on( 'pagecreate',function(event){ 

         db.transaction(getAllEmployees, transactionError);
     });
 }

function getAllEmployees(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('SELECT EmpName,Salary,Gender,Country  FROM  Employee',         [],getEmpSuccess,transactionError);

}

function  getEmpSuccess(tx,result)
{    

  if (result.rows.length)
  {


   for(var i=0;i< result.rows.length; i++)
   {     
       var row = result.rows.item(i);
       $('#EmpList').append('<li><a href="#">' +'<font class="line1">' + '  '+row['EmpName'] + '</font><BR><BR>' +'<font     size="6px" class="line2" > '+ row['Gender']  +'</font>'+'<font size="6px" class="line3"> ' +row['Country']+' </font>'+'<font  size="6px"   class="line4"> '+ row['Salary']+'</font><BR> '+'</a><a href="#" >Delete</a></li>' );


                                                                                                                                                                                                    }


      $('#EmpList').listview('refresh');
       loading('hide');
      }
   }


  function transactionError(tx, error)
 {  
      alert("Database Error: " + error);
 }


 function loading(SH) 
 {
     setTimeout(function(){

   if( SH == "show")
   {
        $.mobile.loading( "show", {
           text:"Loading...",
           textVisible: true,
           theme: "b",
           textonly: false
        });
    }
    else if( SH == "hide")
    {
        $.mobile.loading("hide"); 

    }

      }, 1000); 
   }
```

Comment: use `pagecreate` event.

Comment: @OmarThanks, I have tried it but the problem still

Comment: @OmarIs there another solution for this problem ?

Comment: @OmarCan you help me more please??

Comment: try `pagebeforechange`. note that transitions are fast, and retrieving data from server might take some time.

Comment: @OmarIam retrieving data from sqlite database and its local,I will try this event and i hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: @OmarIhave tried it, the list view and its content didn't shown in the page at all with this event

Comment: `$('#EmployeesListPage #EmpList').append()...`

Comment: @OmarI have tried it , but Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem.  what can we do  now??please

Comment: @OmarCan you help me please?its very important for me to solve this problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45826/discussion-between-omar-and-user)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the transaction runs asynchronously. So, no matter where you put this in the PAGE lifecycle, you will be at risk of experience this "empty-then-not-empty" phenomenon.

Some options that come to mind:

- Show the ajax spinner (see JQM documentation for that) until the callback for your transaction is complete
- Load the necessary data when the app starts and stow it away in a global variable for population during the pagebeforeshow lifecycle event
- Accept the existing behavior

**EDIT:**
Based on your updated code...

I noticed that your HIDE call is done inside the loop through the records. This means that after the first record is appended, the spinner is told to hide. You are also doing a refresh on the content of the control on each iteration as well. I would move the following code to just underneath/past the first right-brace:

```
$('#EmpList').listview('refresh');
loading('hide');
```

This would change it from:

```
   $('#EmpList').listview('refresh');
   loading('hide');
   }
}
```

To:

```
   }
   $('#EmpList').listview('refresh');
   loading('hide');
}
```

Comment: @MattRayThanks a lot for your help , since I have searched and tried many things but the problem still, I tried the first option " Showing loading  " but the loader also appears with the content together at the same Moment ,it didn't appear once showing the page even even if i make $.mobile.loading(...)  before calling the transaction can you help me more in solving this issue please?

Comment: @user No problem. Would you be able to update the code listing to demonstrate what you have so far?

Comment: @MattRayIhave updated my code , as you see i call the loading widget before calling the transaction but the page its shown empty for 2 seconds, then the loader and the content" employees List " are appear together

Comment: @MattRayThanks , I have tried it,  the page is shown empty for 1 second then the list and loader are appear , the loader still not appearing once the Page is shown

Comment: @MattRayCan you help me more Please?

Comment: The delay is really dependent on the time it takes for everything to load. Is this the first page in the app or are you navigating to it from another page?

Comment: @MattRayI navigate to this Page from The Home Page of the Application

Comment: @MattRayIn this case "this Page is not the first Page in the app" there is away to solve this issue? or I have to Accept the existing behavior?